# PrimeNG p-multiselect with options sourced from api doesnt show selected values intermittently

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="commodities | async" formControlName="Customer:commodities" ngClass="v-input" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value"></p-multiSelect>
```

The same commodities array when i use for p-dropdown, there is no issue.

But in multiselect, sometimes it doesnt show the selected value when i first navigate to the page or reload the page

As seen in the below image, the tooltip shows that values are selected but its not displayed.

[image]

This happens only when the options are async. If i use an array from a variable without async pipe, this doesnt happen